# Inserting value in dictionaries

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {"name":"Lloyd", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}

alice = {"name":"Alice", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}

tyler = {"name":"Tyler", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}
```

I am new to programming, at the moment I am learning python programming from codeacademy and udemy.com. Here I have question, since every dictionary above have key name "homework" I want to insert "homework" value as Homework: 90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0. Is it possible to insert 3 dictionary homework value with a same value in a single code ?

Comment: It's competely unclear what the final result is supposed to look like.

Comment: As timgeb said, is there a way you can tell us what the final result should look like?

Comment: I had got the solution of my question sir. Anyway thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a dictionary value like this.

```
tyler = {"name":"Tyler", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}
tyler["homework"]=[90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
print(tyler)
```

Output:

```
{'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0], 'tests': [], 'quizzes': [], 'name': 'Tyler'}
```

Comment: But Sir, isn't it time consuming to write same code for 2 other homework keys.

Comment: Very much so. I took it as more of a "How do I assign a list to this key?" question. In all honesty the question is likely too broad still to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a loop:

```
lloyd = {"name":"Lloyd", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}
alice = {"name":"Alice", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}
tyler = {"name":"Tyler", "homework":[], "quizzes":[], "tests":[]}

people = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

for person in people:
    person["homework"] = [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
```

The output is:

```
{'name': 'Lloyd', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0], 'quizzes': [], 'tests': []}
{'name': 'Alice', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0], 'quizzes': [], 'tests': []}
{'name': 'Tyler', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0], 'quizzes': [], 'tests': []}
```

Still your question is somewhat vague about what exactly you are trying to achive. Maybe edit it with the output you are expecting.

Comment: This is exactly the solution of my question thank you sir.

Comment: @BijayGurung No problem.